# Should a small function be provided if functionality can be derived from the given data?

Tags: oop, class

Consider this class structure :

```
class Test
{
   public:

   vector<string> nameList;

   int getNumberOfUsers();
   int getTotalUsersWithFirstAplhabetA() ;

   void sortTheNameList();
}
```

Since user has access to the users list directly, should I actually provide the small helping functions like finding total users etc, because these functionalities can anyways be drawn out by the user himself?

I am assuming these functions do very small jobs. For functionality requiring bigger logic (like sorting above), am providing the function.

Is it a good design ?

---

Edit:

What I wanted to know was, if I am providing some class information to the user using some function from the interface, should I provide a functionality for getting back the subset of this information also?

Even if I make nameList as private, and provide a *getter* function to retrieve it, my doubt remain the same. Should I provide other smaller functionality also ? or leave them for the user to implement themselves?

Please note that retrieving the complete list is a *definite* requirement for the use cases of my class. But other implementations are not really necessary ?

Comment: The question you should be asking is why you are making the `nameList` public? Is it an intrinsic property of this class that it *must* have a list of names, or is that an implementation detail? Could the nameList sensibly be changed to an array, or a dictionary, or a database, or an XML file? If so, it shouldn't be made public.

Answer (score 1):

The Test class looks a lot like a vector. The only difference are the filters like "only people with A". Make the list private so you can add functionality and try to implement the array interface so you can use it as an array.

Comment: the name is "encapsulation", I believe